# Trigger that will now allow any operation on a table on particular days in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

How do I create a trigger that will not allow any operation (INSERT || UPDATE || DELETE) on table 'Customer' on particular days, e.g. on weekends and 4th of July?

I know that trigger executes a stored procedure on some event(update, insert etc) and that function checks the day of the week if it is weekend it will should cancel that event if not let it happen. My problem is the last part, how do I cancel/execute the events(insert, etc) based on the condition?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What problems are you having?

Comment: @Flimzy I don't have any ideas, can you help me with ideas or logic, not code?

Comment: Do you know how to write a trigger? If so, it should be trivial to add a conditional that checks the day of the week. If you don't know how to write a trigger, you should start by reading the PostgreSQL documentation about how to write triggers.

Comment: I know that trigger executes a stored procedure on some event(update, insert etc) and that function checks the day of the week if it is weekend it will should cancel that event if not let it happen. My problem is the last part, how do I cancel/execute the events(insert, etc) based on the condition? @Flimzy .

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) answers all of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a minimal understanding of [trigger functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) and some [date functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html), you can come up with something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_sunday() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW()) = 0 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'You cannot do this on Sunday!';
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER foo_trigger ON foo
BEFORE INSERT EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_sunday();
```

Comment: `RETURN NEW` part was bothering me. Thank you

Comment: So you had some code you were working on? You should include that in your question.

Comment: After I executed your code, I ran into some problems, i.e. minor syntax errors: If I am not mistaken, 1) `==` operator does not exists in postgresql, it should be `=` 2) create trigger is a little different `CREATE TRIGGER foo_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON foo
EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_holidays();`.